# How to fix headers in ADF tables?

Tags: oracle-adf

How to fix the ADF table header when scrolling that table?
When I am scrolling down the table to see the data the table header should remain displayed. I don't know how to do this in ADF tables.

Answer (score 0):

Size your table to fit into your page - and then this will be the default behavior.
See - http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/table.jspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Shay:):):)

Comment: @shay, How do you size the table ? using width/heigh css property, another property or a layout element ? Which one ?

Comment: You can set a fixed height for the table itself or for the containing layout component. Also - if you are using stretch layout for your page this will be automatic. For example if you use panelStretchLayout and place the table in its center facet this will automatically work.